# Sympy integrate PolynomialDivisionFailed error

Tags: python, sympy

For my research I want to calculate an integral in Python using Sympy. Eventually I want to change some parameters and see how that affects the result but to test my code I first want to do a basic calculation. Unfortunately using the following function:

```
sp.integrate(Z, (x, -sp.oo, sp.oo))
```

With :

`Z = -9.274e-12*(x** 2*(y** 2 + 1)*(-20.0*x** 2 + 15.0*y** 2 + 15.0) + (-0.666666666666667*x** 2 + 0.333333333333333*y** 2 + 0.333333333333333)*(35.0*x** 4 - 30.0*x** 2*(x** 2 + y** 2 + 1) + 3.0*(x** 2 + y** 2 + 1)** 2))*tanh(0.672028985507246*sqrt((1.0*x** 2*(y** 2 + 1) + (-0.666666666666667*x** 2 + 0.333333333333333*y** 2 + 0.333333333333333)** 2)/(x** 2 + y** 2 + 1)** 5))/(sqrt((1.0*x** 2*(y** 2 + 1) + (-0.666666666666667*x** 2 + 0.333333333333333*y** 2 + 0.333333333333333)** 2)/(x** 2 + y** 2 + 1)** 5)*(x** 2 + y** 2 + 1)** 7)`

I get the following error:

```
 PolynomialDivisionFailed: couldn't reduce degree in a polynomial
 division algorithm when dividing [0.444444444444444,
 0.555555555555556*y** 2 + 0.555555555555556, 0.111111111111111*y** 4 + 0.222222222222222*y** 2 + 0.111111111111111] by [-5.08052634253563e-5*y** 18 - 0.000457247370828057*y** 16 -
 0.00182898948331216*y** 14 - 0.00426764212772879*y** 12 - 0.00640146319159407*y** 10 - 0.00640146319159407*y** 8 - 0.00426764212772879*y** 6 - 0.00182898948331216*y** 4 - 0.000457247370828057*y** 2 - 5.08052634253563e-5, -5.08052634253074e-5*y** 20 - 0.000508052634253037*y** 18 - 0.00228623685413862*y** 16 - 0.00609663161103645*y** 14 - 0.0106691053193141*y** 12 - 0.0128029263831771*y** 10 - 0.0106691053193141*y** 8 - 0.00609663161103645*y** 6 - 0.00228623685413862*y** 4 - 0.000508052634253037*y** 2 - 5.08052634253074e-5].  This can happen when it's not possible to detect zero in the coefficient domain. The domain of computation is
 RR[y]. Zero detection is guaranteed in this coefficient domain. This
 may indicate a bug in SymPy or the domain is user defined and doesn't
 implement zero detection properly.
```

By looking into this error I think it is a bug in Sympy but other people sometimes found a work around to let their calculations still compute. Does someone kwow how to get my calculation to compute?

Comment: Try replacing the floats in your expression with rational numbers (you can use `nsimplify` to do this).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) For calculation, take another program based on python (e.g. http://www.sagemath.org/index.html). For now its fine but later on you will face problems with re-calculation etc. Math programms offer a designed UI for that.

2) sometimes it helps sympy by giving the numbers in *x/y* style because ... beeing very accurate 1/3 =! 0.333333333333333 (16th digit)

3) if 2 is not the solution, you can workaround (layman's-style):
think about a numerical integration within boarders of a and b, than decrease a towords -oo and increase b towords oo in a loop. Plotting the results and extrapolating to infinity ... However, a solution should be possible for this problem. I wonder that sympy has problems...(lkely I oversee the error)